# stopping and starting for each loop array in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

i have a for each loop i.e

```
For Each dgvRow In boutgrid.Rows
file = dgvRow.Cells("FileName").Value
AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.url = file
AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play()
Next
```

if want that the loop stops while the player play a file until finished playback

Comment: Is there a way you can get the duration of "file" and set System.Threadding.Threadding.Sleep = 'Duration of file.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just doing some Googlefoo on the AXWindowsMediaPlayer class, you ought to be able to get the duration.  The AxWindowsMediaPlayer class has a [currentMedia](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd562405(VS.85).aspx) field which has a [get_duration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd563436(VS.85).aspx) member which returns the duration in seconds.

Then call [System.Threading.Thread.Sleep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx)(Duration * 1000) because the get_duration returns seconds, and Thread.Sleep is in miliseconds.